# How to scroll to the View Controller top and display a Large Title?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a `ViewControllerOne` with a `tableView` constrained to a `superview` and filled with a content. User can scroll down some content, then switch to `ViewControllerTwo` and change `tableView` data source content on another.

When that happens and user returns to the `ViewControllerOne` I want the VC to be reset on its initial state at the top with a `Large Title` and a new content, but with a workaround I found it scrolls only till the `tableView` top and stops on a `Small Title`.

Here is the code:

1. When user picks a new Data Source in `ViewControllerTwo` I save it as a `bool` in `UserDefaults`:

   ```
     UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "newDataSourcePicked")
   ```
2. In ViewControllerOne I trigger the scrolling method in a `viewWillAppear()`:

   ```
      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
          scrollVCUp()
      }
   ```
3. Here is `scrollVCUp()`. Here I use the saved bool. Also use delay because its not scrolling without it:

   ```
    func scrollVCUp() {
    if newDataSourcePicked {
        traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact ? setVCOffset(with: view.safeAreaInsets.top, and: updateLabelTopInset, delayValue: 0.1) : setVCOffset(with: biggestTopSafeAreaInset, and: updateLabelTopInset, delayValue: 0.1)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "newDataSourcePicked")
    }
   }
   ```
4. Here is `setVCOffset()`:

   ```
    func setVCOffset(with viewInset: CGFloat, and labelInset: CGFloat, delayValue: Double = 0.0) {
       let firstVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? CurrencyViewController
       guard let scrollView = firstVC?.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView else { return }

    if delayValue > 0.0 {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayValue) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(viewInset - labelInset)), animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(viewInset - labelInset)), animated: true)
    }
    }
   ```

I also have a `tabBar` and when I use the same code to scroll `ViewControllerOne` by tapping on a `tabBar` it scrolls and shows a `Large Title`, but doesn't work if we switch to another `VC` and back.

Here is a gif:

[image]

What should I do to scroll and always show a `Large Title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two possible approaches:

**Approach 1**

Don't use the same `UIViewController` instance, that holds the `UITableView`. Create a new one.
(Your case: when `ViewControllerOne` push `ViewControllerTwo`).
With this approach you get the "fresh" layout with large title every time you push the VC.

**Approach 2**

Scroll by calculating the `UITableView.contentOffset`. Use for that `adjustedContentInset.top` and round the value.
With this approach you get the same result like approach 1, but with a visible back scrolling animation.

```swift
class ViewControllerTwo {

    private var _adjustedContentInsetTopRounded: CGFloat?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let y = _adjustedContentInsetTopRounded {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.setContentOffset(
                    CGPoint(
                        x: 0,
                        y: -y
                    ),
                    animated: true
                )
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        _adjustedContentInsetTopRounded = tableView.adjustedContentInset.top.rounded(.up)
    }
}
```